# OpenCV: Can we discover the first and last frame of a bounding box moving?

Tags: python, opencv, bounding-box

Working on python I have a video where I:
First draw a bounding box (bbox).
Next, I need to know the frame on which the bbox starts moving.
Finally, I need to know the last frame on which the bbox stops moving.

**Initial code:**

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np

#open video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('MyVideo.avi')

#total number of frames
totalFrames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
print(totalFrames)

#MOSSE tracker
tracker = cv2.legacy_TrackerMOSSE.create()

#take first frame
ret, frame = cap.read()
image = cv2.resize(frame, (1600,900))

#create bounding box
bbox = cv2.selectROI("Tracking", image, False) #create bounding box
tracker.init(image,bbox)


#define bounding box
def drawBox(image,bbox):
   x, y, w, h = int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]), int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3])
   cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y),((x+w),(y+h)), (255, 0, 255), 3, 1)
   cv2.putText(image, "Tracking", (75, 75), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)

#work within video
while True:

   success, frame = cap.read()
   # resize screen size
   image = cv2.resize(frame, (1600, 900))

#tracker
   success, bbox1 = tracker.update(image)
```

This is the part where I believe I could figure out when my bbox starts moving and print the frame of interes.

```
   if success:
       drawBox(image,bbox1)
       if bbox1 == bbox:
           print('static')
       else:
           print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
   else:
       cv2.putText(image, "Lost", (75, 75), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

Remaining code
#show video
cv2.imshow("feed", image)

```
      if cv2.waitKey(40) == 27:
          break

  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
  cap.release()
```

Comment: ok so... what ideas do you have to approach this? you can already tell if the box moved or not from the previous to the current frame. what's the next piece of information you need?

Comment: Is the bounding box a unique color on the image? If so, you could threshold to find it in the subsequent frames by using cv2.inRange(). Once you have a binary image, the top left x,y of white pixels in the image would be the top left of the bounding box. You could go further and get contours for it and then its bounding box, so that you could get x,y,w,h for it and be sure it has the correct width and height as well as the x,y.

Comment: @fmw42 I think you misunderstood something here. this code clearly *generates* those boxes using a MOSSE tracker and the code already checks if the box moves or not (`if bbox1 == bbox: ...`). this person simply needs some programming 101 (introduce state, react to state changes).

Comment: `@Christoph Rackwit` Yes, sorry, I did misunderstand. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Yes! I am pretty new to Python. So I can take the location of bbox and the current frame, I need the script to look for a difference between the previous position and the current position and spit out that frame.

Same for the final movement of the bbox.

Comment: Why my current script doesn't work is: For some reason bbox1 never actually equals bbox. Even for the first frame it is slightly off:

For frame 2: (no movement yet)
bbox1: (1510.0, 550.5, 216.0, 225.0) bbox: (1514, 553, 213, 217)